# Android: resizing an ImageView in the XML

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have an image that is too big to fit on the screen, and I want it fairly small on screen. How do I change the size of the image through XML?

I tried:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width = "100dp"
android:layout_height= "100dp"
android:scaleType="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:src="@drawable/dashboard_rpm_bottom"
>
</ImageView>
```

But the image isn't resized... it gets cropped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

for example：

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"  
  android:src="@drawable/icon"  
  />
```

Add property `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Answer (score 34):

Mark,

I believe you want to use [`android:scaleType="fitXY"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType).

Comment: Be aware that fitXY distorts the aspect ratio of the image

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this one works for me**:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="60dp" 
  android:layout_gravity="center" 
  android:maxHeight="60dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:src="@drawable/icon"  
  />
```

Comment: So you just copypasted ameyume's answer 8 years later?