# Android: xml image scaling not increasing image size enough

Tags: android, xml, imageview, scale

I'm working on an app with a custom dialog. Inside of that dialog, there is an image that i set in my code depending on which item in a list view is clicked. Everything in the dialog works. The image shows up along with the buttons and text. However the images I am using remain much smaller than I'd like. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267733/android-resizing-imageview-in-xml) tutorial, but it won't scale the images up past a point. It will scale them down, but not up. I have tried various methods to fix this including different `android:scaleType=""`, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to avoid setting the size individually because i have over 400 images, I would like them to be set once and done in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
 android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
 android:saveEnabled="true"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:maxWidth="375dp"  
 android:maxHeight="375dp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

 </ScrollView>

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/Button01"
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:background="@drawable/border"
 android:text="@string/cancel"
 android:textColor="#ffffff" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/Button02"
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:background="@drawable/border"
 android:text="@string/copy"
 android:textColor="#ffffff" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height of the `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`? On a side note, why do you have a `ScrollView` which only contains a `TextView`?

Comment: @Squonk The `RelativeLayout` is a dialog, and the `ScrollView` is just there in case the text gets too big, so that the user can scroll through it, instead of the layout taking up the whole screen.

Comment: You're not storing your images in res/drawable/ but in assets/ Right?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Uh, no. I have made images for multiple screen densities, so I have them in res/drawable/.

Comment: use Resize Image Tools, make the image bigger, so you don't worry it doesn't scale up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your images in the `/res/drawable-nodpi` folder (or change the code accordingly and place them in the `assets/` folder).

Remove those images from the other `drawable/` folders. Tell us their dimensions. Test them on different screens in different orientations. Since these images will be taking the entire width of the screen, you may have to tailor your layout for the different size buckets, but I doubt you'll need to do that for the different density buckets.

Comment: Thanks. I moved all the images to `drawable-nodpi` and all the images increased significantly in size. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DhruvamGupta, Then may be the images you're using are too small to begin with, or there is something else that is wrong. Either way, you should probably start a new question, post your code, and post a link to a sample image you're using.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk size of image was 240x250 and ImageView was 120x120.....when i scaled up size of ImageView to 120x130, there was no change in image size but then i used `android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for ImageView and it is working fine