# Android notification small and big images sizes

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I'm trying to figure out what is the image size used for the notifications in ICS+
As shown here :
[image]

I've tried setting the `ic_launcher` but it was too big and appear to be cut on the image. (48dp for MDPI)
So now i'm using `ic_stat_notify` which is 24dp for MDPI and it looks pretty small.
I went through all the documentation and I couldn't find any mention of these icons size.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can find more about these icons dimensions in Iconography part of the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

You can use [this website](http://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) in order to calculate the exact dimensions

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing your view through a xml layout, you can always scale the ImageView to fit a specific size.

From [Android: resizing imageview in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267733/android-resizing-imageview-in-xml) comes the following example:

```
<ImageView [...]
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom notification using RemoteViews and then, in that custom notification's layout, you can add an ImageView. Set the source of this ImageView to ic_launcher.png or something else. Now, set the height and width from the layout/xml file as per your requirements.