# Android background image cropping

Tags: android

First to say I'm new to android developing, but I have experience with developing in c++, python, php&mysql as well as html and css of course.

I'm playing online text-based mmorpg. Lately they added ability to use your API key in order to access personal account information(e.g. view your energy, cooldowns etc.). So I've come to idea I would make app like "watch" which would push you notifications when e.g. your cooldowns are over.So only thing you would have to do is enter your api key. If I would make this app working(there's no timeframe, because first would be used for my use) I would share it with other users of course. Anyhow, onto the problem!

I was searching google and stackoverflow for similar question, and only thing I stumbled upon as helpful is this: [Android crop background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782294/android-crop-background), however this isn't quitely resolving my problem.

I have image of a size 496x60. I want this image to be cropped horizontally if the device width is smaller than image width, and to have 100% of height. This is image I'm using(from official pc app, but there's no app for android phones): logotorn1(link at the end)

Now what I've done so far(I had button, enter key box, and some text but removed them, so it's only this atm), is this(I'm running the app on my huawei y330 phone): 1

This image seemed a bit squished, so I decided to manually crop the first one and replace it with current image. This is second image: logotorn2

And this is result: 2

This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:foregroundGravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bgimg">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/lel"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java code is irrelevant(?) atm, so I won't post it.

So, the question is, what did I overlook or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Hector

P.S. I've posted all images in one link because it seems I can post only 2 links because of my reputation.

[images](http://postimg.org/gallery/2f3m4uhk4/cf2dfccf/)

Comment: `scaleType` would be where you should look at, as well as the orientation of the image. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/ this link should help your understanding. I would try `center` for your situation.

Comment: It seems this will be really helpful. I appreciate it Elliot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is far simpler than I thought. Problem was in `android:background` instead of `android:src`. I did implement java code together with bitmap variables and OnMeasure thingy, but after looking thoroughly, there was no need for any java code. So if you're having problems with background cropping, first check that your image has `android:src="@drawable/name_of_your_image"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/name_of_your_image"`.

Thanks everyone for help, and sorry for bothering you.

Hector

Answer (score 0):

I have no the exact solutions anyway time ago I have worked on cropping image with Android:

```
 public static ArrayList<Bitmap> splitImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, int rows, int cols) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    int chunkNumbers = rows * cols;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages = new ArrayList<>(chunkNumbers);
    int chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight() / rows;
    int chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / cols;
    Log.d("CHUNK",chunkHeight + " " + chunkWidth);
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        xCoord = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
            chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
    bitmap.recycle();
    System.gc();
    return chunkedImages;
}
```

This method crop an image in a certain numeber of chunkes.
By the way to obtain your you have to obtain the real width and height of your screen device and you can obtain it by overriding onMeasure.

Hope it can help you, bye!

Comment: Thank you as well Danilo. This idea came across my mind. I already have onMeasure code, because I was trying to do something with it. I thought there should be much more easier way instead of writting bunch of code in Java(I can read Java, but never developed anything in it). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:maxWidth="496px"` to your ImageView. This way, it will only scale horizontally if the view is less than 496px (the width of your image). Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267733/android-resizing-imageview-in-xml), I think both answers may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm thinking along the right lines, you could attempt to grab the device width in pixels programatically from your activity.java by

`Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;`

and then set a bitmap to the full image you'd like to use by

`Bitmap b = (Bitmap)findViewById(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE)`

and resize the width of this bitmap by using

`b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, width, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT);`

where 'width' is the device width in pixels obtained previously, and 'ORIGINAL_HEIGHT' is the original height of the image in pixels.

You can then set this new cropped image to the image view you have set in your layout by

`ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.layout.YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);
iv.setImageBitmap(b)`

I hope this helps!